# Laptop for deep learning

Tags: laptop

I would like to get a laptop, preferably with GTX 1080, install Linux on it and run deep learning frameworks such as Caffe or TensorFlow. These are all the requirements regarding the hardware. I have heard, though, that some laptops can have problems with drivers or there can be some incompatibility issues with the GPU under Linux. Is there anybody who made it work on their laptop and could make a recommendation on which laptop the setup worked?

Comment: So you are looking for a laptop with a 1080 GPU that supports Linux. Is there anything else you need in your laptop? Things like Price, screen size, resolution, CPU, RAM, and battery life are helpful to us.

Comment: No, I specified all the requirements. I additionally clarified it. I don't see it as a too-broad question especially that I do not see hardly any answers to this question both here and on the web. I am asking for a specific hardware recommendation on the hardware recommendation website. How can that be off topic?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. This question is off-topic as it doesn't have enough requirements. With a quick search, I found ~80 laptops that might work for you, mostly in the 2-3K price range. If you can add a few more requirements, I'm sure this question can be reopened.

Comment: Sure, thanks for getting back to me but I think there is still a misunderstanding. I know that there are many laptops out there. I did the research. But I am looking for one that somebody used and tested and it works (not that it potentially works). And there are hardly any of them as people use desktops for deep learning. if you found any one of them, then please reopen and post it as an answer.